# Coffeescript, Backbone and load order

Tags: coffeescript, dependency-management

Consider this Coffeescript class, in an app where each class lives in its own file.

```
class Manager extends Person
  title: titles["manager"]
```

If that file is loaded before the "titles" object, an error generated. I'm assuming this is because of Coffeescripts safety wrapper which is performing ".call(this)" when this file is first loaded?

Otherwise, if I were to delay running any code until after the entire page had fully loaded ($(document.ready()), I could be sure that all the javascript files were fully loaded before any code actually ran.

Doesn't this create some annoying load order problems, or am I not doing something correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be both an order issue *and* a wrapper issue. Wrapping something with a function that's run immediately has no effect on order, only on scope.

And if `titles` is defined in another file, then the scoping of `class Manager` doesn't matter. So, it's an order issue. How is `titles` defined?

> if I were to delay running any code until after the entire page had fully loaded ($(document.ready()), I could be sure that all the javascript files were fully loaded before any code actually ran.

Not quite. `$(document).ready()` (note the parentheses—there is no `document.ready` function...) delays a function's execution until all of the page's HTML has been loaded, which doesn't mean all JavaScript has been loaded. Here's the good news: From the standpoint of JavaScript code, it doesn't matter whether other JavaScript files have been loaded, because they're all run in order. (**Note:** I'm assuming here that you're not doing anything fancy like adding additional `<script>` tags from your JavaScript code.)  So as long as you have

```
<script src="titles.js"></script>
<script src="Manager.js"></script>
```

you can rest assured that `Manager.js` will only run after `titles.js` has.

**Warning!** Relying on `$(document).ready()` for ordering JS code is a common mistake that can lead to confusion! If your HTML looked like this

```
<script src="Manager.js"></script>
<script src="titles.js"></script>
```

where `titles.js` creates a global called `titles` and `Manager.js` looks like this

```
$(document).ready ->
  console.log titles
```

then the output will *sometimes* be `titles`, and *sometimes* be `undefined`. Why? Because as [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) say,

> If `.ready()` is called after the DOM has been initialized, the new handler passed in will be executed immediately.

And the DOM may already have been initialized when the first JS file is run! (In practice, this will tend to happen if the browser has the page's HTML cached.)

So, keep it simple. Just load your scripts in the right order. Remember that, for all practical purposes, your scripts are concatenated together by the browser, in order, into a single JS file.

Comment: Wow, thanks Trevor. It's good to know that there's no magic and that I just have to load the scripts in the right order. I was looking at the source of the DocumentCloud website as reference, and it seems their core.jst file (with the global JST object) is the last file to get loaded. I was confused about how classes loaded earlier could reference the JST object, since I was seeing an error doing it that way in my own app.

Answer (score 2):

Give a try to CoffeeToaster:
http://github.com/serpentem/coffee-toaster

It'll do exactly what you're looking for by providing `import` directive, which is `#<<`, i.e.:

```
#<< foldera/folderb/folderc/myfile
```

You don't need to inform the `.coffee` extension, plus you can turn on the `packaging` option to have namespaces facilities, if you're used to something like:

```
#<< another/package/myclass
class SomeClass extends another.package.MyClass
```

It has a build system that will output a single javascript file for you, or several (in debug mode) for easing the debugging process.

Take a look on the `README` and the usage example at:
https://github.com/serpentem/coffee-toaster/tree/master/usage

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a load order problem, and `titles` in `Manager` refers to a global in this case, that isn't declared at this point. If you know `titles` is declared globally somewhere else, you must manually ensure that script has been loaded first. And yes, the problem may very well be with the safety wrapper. But just as a recommendation: it's there for a good reason. Create yourself a namespace instead that you export to the global object. The global object lives in `this` (at definition time) or `exports` in Node. I usually put this one-liner on top of scripts that should have easy access to the global object:

```
root = exports ? window
```

From there I can put things in the global object, like a namespace:

```
root.app =
  a: 1,
  a_fun: -> 1

class root.app.Cls
   method: => 1 + 1

root.app.obj = new root.app.Cls
```

Now, there will be an 'app' object in your global object with a 'class' (so to speak) and and object.